# RHEL Installation issue with UEFI on HP Compaq Desktop

Tags: rhel, boot, system-installation, dual-boot, uefi

I have bought a new Desktop HP Compaq Elite 8300 SFF. It came with Windows 7 Pro installed.

Now I want to install Linux (RHEL) by dual booting it.
I have successfully shrinked the partition and rebooted the system.

But, after booting through RHEL DVD, the system hangs after few initialization messages.

Secondly, I rebooted, boot from cdrom, There are 3 options:

1. Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.0
2. Install system with basic video drivers
3. Rescue

If I press 'e' tab from to edit I got the following option

```
kernel /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
initrd /image/pxeboot/initrd.img
```

But I don't know what to edit in this.

I am getting the same error with some initial messages and system hangs after selecting any of above 3 options.

Third option,

`Startup Menu--> Run UEFI Application --> CDROM_DVD_RAM GH82N--> EFI
 --> BOOT --> BOOTX64.EFI`

But here I got only blank grub menu

```
grub>
```

I don't know what to write in this. Or am I doing something wrong?

The issue is not with DVD for sure, because I have original RHEL DVD and the same problem with other 2 DVDs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but it was a very silly think, I must say.

I just entered in boot priority option in Setup.

There are 2 major options enabled.
1. EFI boot Devices
   (Under this number of options like Floppy, CD/DVD, HDD)
2. Legacy boot Devices
    (Under this number of options like Floppy, CD/DVD, HDD)

I just disabled 1st option (i.e. EFI boot Devices), and my problem solved :)