# How to make UEFI bootable usb disk from bios bootable iso

Tags: boot, uefi

Suppose you have an iso image that contains a bios bootable partition.
You can write this image to a usb disk

In linux you could do this for example with

```
dd if=pmagic_2013_02_28.iso of/dev/sdc1
```

Your USB disk is now bootable on computers with bios. 
However on my UEFI system, the usb disk does not boot. How can you make it EFI bootable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RHEL Installation issue with UEFI](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64655/rhel-installation-issue-with-uefi). Different OS but offers canonical solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some magic of El Torito is required when creating the iso image. See [this](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User%3aPjones/BootableCDsForBIOSAndUEFI#New_UEFI.2FBIOS_hybrid_method).

Answer (score 0):

For the image to be (U)EFI bootable, it needs to have a primary VFAT32 partition containing the initramfs image file to be booted under the path `/efi/boot/bootx64.efi`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your only chance is to rebuild the ISO image and add the UEFI files needed for it. With `xorriso` you can do that.

First, extract the contents of the original ISO file:

`xorriso -osirrox on -indev IMAGE.ISO -extract / ISO_DIR`

Then you need to create the ESP (EFI System Partition), which has to be a FAT partition. We will create a file that contains such partition:

```bsh
BOOT_IMG=efi.img

grub-mkimage \
    -C xz \
    -O x86_64-efi \
    -p /boot/grub \
    -o bootx64.efi \
    boot linux normal configfile \
    part_gpt btrfs fat iso9660 loopback \
    test keystatus gfxmenu regexp \
    efi_gop efi_uga all_video gfxterm font \
    echo read ls cat png jpeg halt

mkfs.vfat -C $BOOT_IMG \
    $(( ($(stat -c %s bootx64.efi) / 1024 + 511) / 32 * 32 ))

mmd -i $BOOT_IMG ::/efi
mmd -i $BOOT_IMG ::/efi/boot
mmd -i $BOOT_IMG ::/boot
mmd -i $BOOT_IMG ::/boot/grub

mcopy -Q -i $BOOT_IMG bootx64.efi ::/efi/boot

# You may create a grub.cfg file if you want.
[ -f grub.cfg ] &&
    mcopy -Q -i $BOOT_IMG grub.cfg ::/boot/grub
```

Once the ESP is generated, you can build a UEFI bootable ISO image with:

```bsh
xorriso -as mkisofs \
    -r -J -l \
    -iso-level 3 \
    -joliet-long \
    -append_partition 2 0xef $BOOT_IMG \
    -partition_cyl_align all \
    -o uefi-bootable.iso \
    ISO_DIR
```

Your ISO image will be created as `uefi-bootable.iso` in your current directory.

---

You can read these resources about bootable ISO images:

- https://wiki.debian.org/RepackBootableISO
- https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/blob/master/tools/mkimage-iso-efi/make-efi
- https://github.com/Nitrux/mkiso/blob/master/mkiso
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface
- https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/