# RHEL 6.7 kickstart using minimal boot media on UEFI

Tags: rhel, uefi, kickstart

I'm new to RHEL (haven't used it since the early 2000s when it was still open source) and currently attempting to install it on a cluster of machines. I'm trying to automate this process as much as possible.

To that end, I've created a custom kickstart file `ks.cfg` and placed it on a webserver (`http://url.com/ks.cfg`). I've also placed the RHEL 6.7 server ISO on the same webserver, and [created a minimal boot image on a USB drive that can handle my machines (UEFI)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/Making_Minimal_Boot_Media-UEFI.html). It boots off the USB stick just fine.

However, I reach the same GRUB menu as the user in this [somewhat-related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64655/rhel-installation-issue-with-uefi-on-hp-compaq-desktop). It appears to be grub 0.97, rather than the GRUB2 all the tutorials I've found online are using. Of particular note, this version does not seem to recognize the critical `linux` command, which all the tutorials I've found reference for appending the `ks=` arguments.

**In short, how do I bring up the `boot:` prompt so I can issue the `linux ks=` command?** Any help is appreciated!

(and if you want to throw in some information on how to set up a PXE server for fully-automated network installs, I'm all ears; the documentation is not particularly helpful, at least in terms of the PXE server specifically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest might be to tweak the `efidisk.img` to do what you want, something along the lines of:

```
cp /that/cdrom/efiboot.img /root
mount -o loop /root/efiboot.img /mnt
cd /mnt/EFI/BOOT
```

and there should be a (under RHEL7 or equivalent) `grub.conf`. Then, edit that, in particular the `linuxefi` line inside the `menuentry 'Install ...'` block, to contain something like

```
        linuxefi /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz inst... ks=http://... quiet
```

then unmount that, re`dd` the image over to the flash drive, lather, wash, rinse, repeat.

On RHEL6, look for a `BOOT*.conf` file, which has PXE boot config lines with `title`; try adding an append line with the kickstart argument:

```
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7
        kernel ...
        initrd ...
        append ks=http://...
```

(You may also need `ksdevice=eth0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` arguments to force use of the "first" network card and to turn off wacky device naming, from digging around in our build system.)

PXE setup is somewhat involved, as you need to offer DHCP, TFTP, and usually also HTTP to serve files from, plus maybe DNS, and there's particular fiddly bits you need to get right in all of those services, in addition to getting a valid kickstart file going. Something like the http://www.rocksclusters.org/wordpress/ project might be worth looking at for "a cluster", in lieu of delving deeper in to the redhat docs.

Comment: Huh, this is interesting. When I run `kpartx` and then `mount` (I have to modify the argument to be `mount -t vfat /dev/mapper/loop2p1 /mnt`), I get the `/mnt/EFI/BOOT` folder but it only contains 5 files: `BOOTX64.conf`,  `BOOTX64.efi`,  `initrd.img`,  `splash.xpm.gz`, and `vmlinuz`. Did I mount the wrong EFI partition?

Comment: Oh, I was poking at a Centos 7 image. *cough* Let me find something from RHEL6...

Comment: If it wasn't for my uni's *Satellite* subscription, I'd almost just go with CentOS at this point...

Comment: Okay, just tweak the `BOOTX64.conf`. Similar, but different.

Comment: Silly question: after editing the file and unmounting the directory, how do I recreate the image with the new conf file?

Comment: You're editing the filesystem on the image directly, so I don't think you need to remake anything, just `dd` the thus updated image to your boot media.

Comment: If I re-mount the image after unmounting and deleting the loop, I don't see any edits to the conf file. Furthermore, the .img file itself doesn't have an updated timestamp. I'm new to this so I'm not sure what to expect, so my intuition here could very well be wrong :P